# How to make working my structure with EF Core using Fluent Api?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

I'm trying to represent some kind of tree using ef core and postgre sql. I have two classes:

```
public class ProtocolNode
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ProtocolCriteria> Criterias { get; set; }

    public ProtocolNode()
    {
        Criterias = new List<ProtocolCriteria>();
    }

}

public class ProtocolCriteria
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public Guid? ParentId { get; set; }

    public ProtocolNode Parent { get; set; }

    public Guid? ChildrenId { get; set; }

    public ProtocolNode Children { get; set; }
}
```

After that, I'm trying to run migrations for creating a database, but getting the error:

**Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property 'ProtocolCriteria.Parent' of type 'ProtocolNode'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.**

I assume that I need to make some rules using Fluent API, but after some attempts I'm stuck...
I would be thankful for any help.

Comment: Since ProtocolCriteria has a parent child of the same type(ProtocolNode ), you need 2 collections in ProtocolNode (ParentCriterias & ChildCriterias). You can use the [InverseProperty attribute](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/inverseproperty-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx) to connect them up or fluent code.

Answer (score 0):

In general, a top-down tree structure consists of equal nodes which have two major properties, parent & siblings

```
public class node {
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int? ParentId {get; set;}  // top node has no parent
    public virtual Node Parent {get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Node> Children {get; set;}
}

builder.Entity<Node>()     // ModelBuilder
    .HasOptional(c => c.Parent)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(c => c.ParentId);
```

EF makes parsing the children much easier than maintaining Linked-Lists.  This assumes you are NOT talking about Binary trees which are a special case.

Note: EF Core has not implemented the HasOptional() functionality yet.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. My goal is to build a criteria tree. For example a node has 1 or more criterias. Each criteria has a reference to the another node. After building a tree I put into this tree a list of conditions and do a passage through the tree. On each node I'm finding  out the true criteria (comparing needed values from the list of conditions with each criteria in the node) and go to the node which is stored in this criteria. So, I have to use the structured I described above.

Comment: Could you explain this: "On each node I'm finding out the true criteria (comparing needed values from the list of conditions with each criteria in the node)"  Traversing the tree structure meets your OP but that line is not clear.

Comment: EF Core doesn't have a `HasOptional()` builder.

Comment: That's what I said.  That clause can be removed for Core since convention will make it optional since the foreign key is nullable.